# Why use Unicode if your program is English only?

Tags: unicode

So I've read [Joel's article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), and looked through SO, and it seems the only reason to switch from ASCII to Unicode is for internationalization.  The company I work for, as a policy, will only release software in English, even though we have customers throughout the world.  Since all of our customers are scientists, they have functional enough English to use our software as a non-native speaker.  Or so the logic goes.  Because of this policy, there is no pressing need to switch to Unicode to support other languages.

However, I'm starting a new project and wanted to use Unicode (because that is what a responsible programmer is supposed to do, right?).  In order to do so, we would have to start converting all of the libraries we've written into Unicode.  This is no small task.

If internationalization of the programs themselves is not considered a valid reason, how would one justify all the time spent recoding libraries and programs to make the switch to Unicode?

Comment: "it seems the only reason to switch from ASCII to UNICODE is for internationalization"  Far from true.  Why do you make that claim?  Where have you seen that as the ONLY reason?

Comment: I used "it seems" because I don't know of any other reason.  Please educate me.

Comment: Unicode isn't an acronym, you know </grumpy>

Comment: @skaffman: you're right, I fixed it

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This obviously depends on what your app actually does, but just because you only have an english version in no way means that internationalization is not an issue.

What if I want to store a customer name which uses non-english characters? Or the name of a place in another country?

As an added bonus (since you say you're targeting scientists) is that all sorts of scientific symbols and notiations are supported as part of Unicode.

Ultimately, I find it much easier to be consistent. Unicode behaves the same no matter whose computer you run the app on. Non-unicode means that you use some locale-dependant character set or codepage by default, and so text that looks fine on your computer may be full of garbage characters on someone else's.

Apart from that, you probably don't need to translate *all* your libraries to Unicode in one go. Write wrappers as needed to convert between Unicode and whichever encoding you use otherwise.

If you use UTF-8 for your Unicode text, you even get the ability to read plain ASCII strings, which should save you some conversion headaches.

Answer (score 15):

They say they will always put it in English now, but you admit you have worldwide clients.  A client comes in and says internationalization is a deal breaker, will they really turn them down?

To clarify the point I'm trying to make you say that they will not accept this reasoning, but it is sound.

Always better to be safe than sorry, IMO.

Comment: Additionally, it's easier to support Unicode from the beginning, than try to retrofit it later, when some client demands it.

Comment: Technically isn't this a classic straw man argument?  Using a non-existent problem to try to win an argument.  I think jalf's argument is stronger in that it points out concrete benefits of Unicode.  However if bsruth (or his marketing dept) was to canvas clients and find out if Unicode was important to them - then that could provide a concrete business case, to which his management should consider.

Comment: That's not really the focus of what a "straw man" is, technically :)

Answer (score 15):

The extended Scientific, Technical and Mathematical character set rules.

Where else can you say ⟦∀c∣c∈Unicode⟧ and similar technical stuff.

Answer (score 12):

Characters beyond the 7-bit ASCII range are useful in English as well. Does anyone using your software even need to write the € sign? Or £? How about distinguishing "résumé" from "resume"?You say it's used by scientists around the world, who may have names like "Jörg" or "Guðmundsdóttir". In a scientific setting, it is useful to talk about wavelengths like λ, units like Å, or angles as Θ, even in English.

Some of these characters, like "ö", "£", and "€" may be available in 8-bit encodings like ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252, so it may seem like you could just use those encodings and be done with it. The problem is that there are characters outside of those ranges that many people use very frequently, and so lots of existing data is encoded in UTF-8. If your software doesn't understand that when importing data, it may interpret the "£" character in UTF-8 as a sequence of 2 Windows-1252 characters, and render it as "Â£". If this sort of error goes undetected for long enough, you can start to get your data seriously garbled, as multiple passes of misinterpretation alter your data more and more until it becomes unrecoverable.

And it's good to think about these issues early on in the design of your program. Since strings tend to be very low-level concept that are threaded throughout your entire program, with lots of assumptions about how they work implicit in how they are used, it can be very difficult and expensive to add Unicode support to a program later on if you have never even thought about the issue to begin with.

My recommendation is to always use Unicode capable string types and libraries wherever possible, and make sure any tests you have (whether they be unit, integration, regression, or any other sort of tests) that deal with strings try passing some Unicode strings through your system to ensure that they work and come through unscathed.

If you don't handle Unicode, then I would recommend ensuring that all data accepted by the system is 7-bit clean (that is, there are no characters beyond the 7-bit US-ASCII range). This will help avoid problems with incompatibilities between 8-bit legacy encodings like the ISO-8859 family and UTF-8.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose your program allows me to put my name in it, on a form, a dialog, whatever, and my name can't be written with ascii characters... Even though your program is in English, the data may be in other language...

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't matter that your software is not translated, if your users use international characters then you need to support unicode to be able to do correct capitalization, sorting, etc.

Comment: Internationalisation is much more than just using unicode. It won't solve the sorting, capitalisation and other issues for you.

Answer (score 6):

If you have no business need to switch to unicode, then don't do it.  I'm basing this on the fact that you thought you'd need to change code unrelated to component you already need to change to make it all work with Unicode.  If you can make the component/feature you're working on "Unicode ready" without spreading code churn to lots of other components (especially other components without good test coverage) then go ahead and make it unicode ready.  But don't go churn your whole codebase without business need.

If the business need arises later, address it then.  Otherwise, you aren't going to need it.

People in this thread may suppose scenarios where it becomes a business requirement.  Run those scenarios by your product managers before considering them scenarios worth addressing.  Make sure they know the cost of addressing them when you ask.

Answer (score 5):

Well for one, your users might know and understand english, but they can still have 'local' names. If you allow your users to do any kind of input to your application, they might want to use characters that are not part of ascii. If you don't support unicode, you will have no way of allowing these names. You'd be forcing your users to adopt a more simple name just because the application isn't smart enough to handle special characters.

Another thing is, even if the standard right now is that the app will only be released in English, you are also blocking the possibility of internationalization with ASCII, adding to the work that needs to be done when the company policy decides that translations are a good thing. Company policy is good, but has also been known to change.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say this attitude expressed naïveté, but I wouldn't be able to spell naïveté in ASCII-only.

ASCII still works for some computer-only codes, but is no good for the façade between machine and user.

Even without the New Yorker's old-fashioned style of coöperation, how would some poor woman called Zoë cope if her employers used such a system?

Alas, she wouldn't even seek other employment, as updating her résumé would be impossible, and she'd have to resume instead. How's she going to explain that to her fiancée?

Answer (score 4):

> The company I work for, **as a policy**, will only release software in English, even though we have customers throughout the world.

1 reason only: Policies change, and when they change, they will break your existing code. Period.

[Design for evil](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001123.html), and you have a chance of not breaking your code so soon. In this case, use Unicode. Happened to me on a brazilian specific stock-market legacy system.

Answer (score 3):

Many languages (Java [and thus most JVM-based language implementations], C# [and thus most .NET-based language implementatons], Objective C, Python 3, ...) support Unicode strings by preference or even (nearly) exclusively (you have to go out of your way to work with "strings" of bytes rather than of Unicode characters).

If the company you work for ever intends to use any of these languages and platforms, it would therefore be quite advisable to start planning a Unicode-support strategy; a pilot project in particular might not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

That's a really good question. The only reason I can think of that has nothing to do with I18n or non-English text is that Unicode is particularly suited to being what might be called a hub character set. If you think of your system as a hub with its external dependencies as spokes, you want to isolate character encoding conversions to the spokes, so that your hub system works consistently with your chosen encoding. What makes Unicode a ideal character set for the hub of your system is that it acknowledges the existence of other character sets, it defines equivalences between its own characters and characters in those external character sets, and there's an ongoing process where it extends itself to keep up with the innovation and evolution of external character sets. There are all sorts of weird encodings out there: even when the documentation assures you that the external system or library is using plain ASCII it often turns out to be some variant like IBM775 or HPRoman8, and the nice thing about Unicode is that no matter what encoding is thrown at you, there's a good chance that there's a table on unicode.org that defines exactly how to convert that data into Unicode and back out again without losing information. Then again, equivalents of a-z are fairly well-defined in every character set, so if your data really is restricted to the standard English alphabet, ASCII may do just as well as a hub character set.

A decision on encoding is a decision on two things - what set of characters are permitted and how those characters are represented. Unicode permits you to use pretty much any character ever invented, but you may have your own reasons not to want or need such a wide choice. You might still restrict usernames, for example, to combinations of a-z and underscore, maybe because you have to put them into an external LDAP system whose own character set is restricted, maybe because you need to print them out using a font that doesn't cover all of Unicode, maybe because it closes off the security problems opened up by lookalike characters. If you're using something like ASCII or ISO8859-1, the storage/transmission layer implements a lot of those restrictions; with Unicode the storage layer doesn't restrict anything so you might have to implement your own rules at the application layer. This is more work - more programming, more testing, more possible system states. The tradeoff for that extra work is more flexibility, application-level rules being easier to change than system encodings.

Comment: I didn't even think about ensuring a font supports UNICODE.  How would one do that, programatically?

Comment: For the parts of the system where you control the fonts, there are Unicode fonts available that should cover most of what you need. For the parts where the users control the fonts, you might have to specify in the help documentation what fonts are required, but this may not have to be a big thing - in practice the users who want to write (say) Korean are likely to be Korean and already have the required fonts installed. Where a third party controls the fonts (for a library or external system), it's something to discuss with that vendor.

Comment: @bsruth that's what font renders will handle. If a font lacks a character they'll look for substitutes from other fonts.

Answer (score 3):

The reason to use unicode is to respect proper abstractions in your design.

Just get used to treating the concept of **text** properly. It is not hard. There's no reason to create a broken design even if your users are English.

Answer (score 2):

Just think of a customer wanting to use names like *Schrödingers Cat* for files he saved using your software. Or imagine some localized Windows with a translation of *My Documents* that uses non-ASCII characters. That would be internationalization that has, though you don't support internationalization at all, have effects on your software.

Also, having the option of supporting internationalization later is always a good thing.

Comment: Yes, this! A co-worker of mine has his name as his windows login. Every now and then an app starts breaking when it receives a folder path such as `C:\Users\João\Desktop\something`. Even if he didn't have that character in his window account, it could happen from a valid folder name such as `verão 2015` ("summer 2015").

Answer (score 1):

Unicode is like [cooties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooties). Once it "infects" one area, it's usually hard to contain it given interconnectedness of dependencies. Sooner or later, you'll probably have to tie in a library that is unicode compliant and thus will use wchar_t's or the like. Instead of marshaling between character types, it's nice to have consistent strings throughout.

Thus, it's nice to be consistent. Otherwise you'll end up with something similar to the Windows API that has a "A" version and a "W" version for most APIs since they weren't consistent to start with. (And in some cases, Microsoft has [abandoned creating "A" versions altogether](http://www.siao2.com/2006/10/24/867880.aspx).)

Answer (score 1):

Internationalization is so much more than just text in different languages. I bet it's the niche of the future in the IT-world. Heck, it already is. A lot has already been said, just thought I would add a small thing. Even though your customers right now are satisfied with english, that might change in the future. And the longer you wait, the harder it will be to convert your code base. They might even today have problems with e.g. file names or other types of data you save/load in your application.

Comment: I guess in 2021 too, many big softwares ( And I'm saying this having experience in software industry ) run 'just fine' without Unicode support. I'm mainly talking about B2B software products which don't have general public as end-users.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what language you're using. In some languages, changing from ASCII to Unicode may be pretty easy, whereas in others (which don't support Unicode) it might be pretty darn hard.

That said, maybe in your situation you shouldn't support Unicode: you can't think of a compelling reason why you should, and there are some reasons (i.e. your cost to change your existing libraries) which argue against. I mean, perhaps 'ideally' you should but in practice there might be some other, more important or more urgent, thing to spend your time and effort on at the moment.

Comment: For the most part, I'm using C++, but I'm mainly interested in reasons (other than translation) to use Unicode.

Comment: Well ... the O/S uses Unicode natively; if you're using ASCII filename the O/S needs to convert those to Unicode, so if you were using Unicode the whole thing might be slightly faster. But although that's a reason I'd say that's typically not a sufficient reason.

Answer (score 1):

If program takes text input from the user, it should use unicode; you never know what language the user is going to use.

Comment: `you never know what language the user is going to use`: yes he does, it's English. It's a company policy, as is written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When using Unicode, it leaves the door open for internationalization if requirements ever change and you are required to use text in other languages than English.

Also, in your new project you could always just write wrappers for the libraries that internally convert between ASCII and Unicode and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Your potential client may already be running a non-unicode application in a language other than English and won't be able to run your program without swichting the windows unicode locale back and forth, which will be a big pain.

Answer (score 0):

Because the internet is overwhelmingly using Unicode.  Web pages use unicode.  Text files including your customer's documents, and the data on their clipboards, is Unicode.

Secondly Windows, is natively Unicode, and the ANSI APIs are a legacy.

Modern applications should use Unicode where applicable, which is almost everywhere.