# Should FormatMessageA() formats the message in correct way even on a unicode OS?

Tags: c++, winapi, locale

I am not completely understand the difference between two functions FormatMessageA() and FormatMessageW(). It is clear that FormatMessageW() will always give the correct message whatever is the language in my OS.

But what if I have language other than English should FormatMessageA() still give me the correct result in English?

I have the following code:

```
static std::string GetLastErrorAsString()
{
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    if (errorMessageID == 0)
    {
        return std::string();
    }

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;

    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    std::string message(messageBuffer, size);
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);

    return message;
}
```

Will the following function work correctly with any language in the OS?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "correctly"? And why would you want to be using `FormatMessageA` in any case? Hard to imagine a valid reason to prefer it over `FormatMessageW`.

Comment: Under correctly I mean will it format me the message in ascii in any OS language?

Comment: `FormatMessageA` do the same as `FormatMessageW` and then call `RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString`. so by fact - your question - are `RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString` convert correctly with any language ? no of course. not any language can be converted to ansi.

Comment: @RbMm though generally the current windows code page should be able to represent messages in the current system language

Comment: @AlanBirtles - yes, in general, when we convert `GetLastError` value, must fit to current system Windows ANSI code page.

Comment: Actually all I want is to have error messages in English, that's all. I am trying to avoid using wchar_t.

Comment: The system is using wchar_t, even when you call the A suffix functions

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `wchar_t`? Put another way: Why do you want to avoid a solution that will always provide the correct result, uses less memory allocations, and is computationally cheaper?

Comment: If I use MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US) should it always give me the string in English?

Comment: It will, if the respective language resources are available. But not without having to convert from UTF-16. Why do you insist on performing a possibly lossy and guaranteed to be more costly operation? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Just for this question. If you pass a specific `LANGID`, `FormatMessage` will only return messages with that `LANGID`.  So your understanding is correct. But you want your program to work normally in all languages, I still recommend that you use Unicode encoding. See [Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode) and [Why use Unicode if your program is English only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997681/why-use-unicode-if-your-program-is-english-only)

Comment: I understood, thanks.